# U.S. and Turkey geopolitical relationship

Tags: united-states, turkey, geopolitics

Are the U.S. and Turkey allies?

Answer (score 2):

Currently they are both NATO members, which makes them by definition allies, but their relationship is strained.

- The USAF is still based in [Incirlik](https://www.incirlik.af.mil/).
- The governments are [strongly at odds](https://www.politico.com/story/2019/01/13/trump-turkey-isis-syria-withdrawal-1098798) over Syria.